# How can I straighten up the line between two nodes in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

How can I straighten up the line between two nodes in Inkscape?

I need the part on the screenshot to be straight and not curly as it is right now.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select each of these nodes with the Edit by Nodes Tool (N)
2. hit the *Make Selected Nodes Corner* button in the tool controls along the top. Depending on the kind of node, you may need to press the button once or twice.

[image]

Comment: Omg. Thank u so much. I knew about that tool, but I thought that I understand it wrong. Because nothing happens with the first click, but works fine with the second click.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have got tired to fix moved node handles after trying to do it with the node tool. Here's a workaround:

[image]

Have node snaps ON and draw a closed polygon path (=red) by clicking with the Bezier tool (=the Pen). Subtract it from the original. This method saves ALL other curved parts, nothing else is straightened nor moved.

This works also with open original path, but you must remove the automatically inserted closing segment to make the path open again.

**ADD:** The comment shows that you expect something else than straightening just a single curve segment absolutely without other effects. If it happens that every curve segment should be straightened at the same time with a single operation but still keeping all nodes where they are you should apply Extensions > Modify Path > Flatten Bezier

Comment: How did you create the red shape? That was my question. I have a curvy shape and I need it to be just like the red shape.

Comment: The red shape is made by only clicking with the Bezier curve drawing tool, 5 clicks for the closed 4 corner polygon. To replicate it be sure to set the tool to Regular Bezier mode, not Spline drawing mode or Spiro mode. Straight line segment mode is also OK. Tool options are normally shown just below the menu bar above the drawing area.